# autocomplete for textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPInf" Width="60" placeholder="PartnerId" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I know I can use the `<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>`, but could you recommend me a jquery alternative?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ check this

Comment: A bit of Google search is advisble. Also, See [Jquery AutoComplete Example](http://dotnetmentors.com/aspnet/jquery-autocomplete-by-example.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For jQuery autocomplete you need to add below CSS and js files.

1. jquery-ui.css
2. jquery-x.xx.x.js
3. jquery-ui.js

You can download these files from the jQuery sites - https://jquery.com/download/

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="lblName">Name: </label>
  <input id="Names">
</div>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var arrNames = [
      "A",
      "Abc",
      "Abcd",
      "Bcd",
      "d"
    ];
    $( "#Names" ).autocomplete({
      source: arrNames
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: I have implemented above solution on 'http://jsfiddle.net'. 

Could you please check below link and try again.

http://jsfiddle.net/pUeue/2637/

Answer (score 0):

The most simple one is [jQuery UI's AutoComplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: A concrete example ( as above - which it's not working ) would be nice

Comment: I don't have a ready to send end to end example.  There isn't anything special that needs to be handled to get it working though.  gkrishy's comment I know is close to a good example.

Answer (score 0):

To use it in asp.net web project you can take a look [at this](http://www.dotnetspan.com/2014/08/jquery-autocomplete-example-using-aspnet.html) solution, this basically works on the principal of jquery and web method.

You can use Jquery's inbuilt auto complete functionality, take a look at the guide from here https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Script Refernce and calling JQuery AutoComplete Plugin in .aspx Page**

I have created a new website and added below code in default.aspx page.

**Note: I have done this as per your requirement "TextBox"**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>JQuery AutoComplete TextBox Demo</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div><h1>AutoComplete Textbox</h1>
City:
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js"</script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#txtCity").autocomplete({
source: function (request, response) {
var param = { cityName: $('#txtCity').val() };
$.ajax({
url: "Default.aspx/GetCities",
data: JSON.stringify(param),
dataType: "json",
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
success: function (data) {
response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
return {
value: item
}
}))
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert(textStatus);
}
});
},
minLength: 2//minLength as 2, it means when ever user enter 2 character in   TextBox the AutoComplete method will fire and get its source data. 
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebMethod to Fetch City from NorthWind Database**

I have added a WebMethod "GetCities" in default.aspx.cs to  call it in Source of JQuery Autocomplete

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetCities(string cityName)
{
    List<string> City = new List<string>();
    string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT City FROM Customers WHERE City LIKE '%{0}%'", cityName);
    //Note: you can configure Connection string in web.config also.
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = .\SQLEXPRESS2008R2; initial Catalog = NORTHWND; Integrated Security = true"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                City.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }
    return City;
}
```

Source : [Dotnetcodepress](http://dotnetcodepress.com/Articles/ASP-dot-net/jquery-ui-autocomplete-textbox-from-database-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      // Result Grade Autocomplete.
    const data = ['A+','A','A-','B+','B','B-','C+','C','D'];
    $(function() {
        $( ".gpawa" ).autocomplete({
        source: data,
        });
    });
});
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  
GPA :  <input required style="width: 50px" type="text" name="GPAWA1[2]" id="GPAWA_H" class="form-control gpawa" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```